# Should I be worried that my ceiling light has current when turned "off"?

Tags: electrical, lighting, leak, grounding

I am based in the UK. I was replacing a ceiling light when I noticed an issue.

When I used a voltage screwdriver the live wire in the **ceiling** pendant was showing a voltage present even when the wall switch is switched off (not expected)

When I switch the wall switch to "on" the tester glows stronger (which is what I expected)

The lamp in the ceiling pendant **does** go off when the switch is**off**.

So I took the cover off the wall switch and tested the metal box base which appears to be earthed but still shows a voltage present too!

Should I be worried?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the switch switches the live wire and not the neutral wire?

Comment: Yes it's definitely the live wire

Comment: Throw away that voltage screwdriver before you electrocute yourself. The way they work is by slightly electrocuting the person using it.